# Can use get(position) on adapter with custom class

Tags: android

I made a custom User class to be used as my data source for the adapter, but the following method can not be resolved now in the `onBindViewHolder`

```
private ArrayList<User> mDataset;

// Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
public MyAdapter(ArrayList<User> myDataset) {
    mDataset = myDataset;
}

public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    myHolder = holder;        
    myHolder.myTextView.setText((mDataset.get(position))); // cannot resolve
}
```

How to make the `get(position)` work with my custom User class?

Answer (score 2):

`mDataset.get(position)` will return your `User` instance at the given position. You should access the property you want to set to the TextView: `mDataset.get(position).yourProperty`

Answer (score 1):

For more accurate results use `getAdapterPosition()`.

Also you need to get value of property that you can pass to `setText()`.

```
myHolder.myTextView.setText((mDataset.get(myHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getYourProperty()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can't  `myHolder.myTextView.setText();` expects a string as a parameter and you are passing a `User`.
Decide what do you want to show in your textView and get it From Your `User` example
`myHolder.myTextView.setText((mDataset.get(position).name));` :
if the name is public or else if its private just generate `Getters` and `Setters` with Alt + insert inside your User class
and use it like below: `myHolder.myTextView.setText((mDataset.get(position).getName()));`